# How to save cv2.imwrite into a variable and called it in cv.imread

Tags: python, data-science, opencv, imread

I am using cv2.imwrite to save my new edited image. Now I want to call that in cv.imread. I want to write my new image to variable so I can call that variable in cv.imread but it looks like cv.imread dont read the variable.

Currently I am doing as follows

```
cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/Imp/MyKey16.png", EditImg)
img1 = cv.imread('C:/Users/Imp/MyKey16.png',0)
```

Instead of it I want to go for;

```
EditedImage = cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/Imp/MyKey16.png", EditImg)
img1 = cv.imread(EditedImage)
```

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible, because `imread` takes a string as argument (filename) while `iwrite` second argument is a `cv::Mat`. Why don't you store the filename in a variable?

```
filename = 'C:/Users/Imp/MyKey16.png'
EditedImage = cv2.imwrite(filename, EditImg)
img1 = cv.imread(filename)
```

But again, unless you have some valid reason, there should be no need to save the image locally, just copy the `cv::Mat` as suggested in the answer of Muhammed Yücel.

Comment: I have edited one image which I just want to read. It is OK if its not get saved but it should be read by cv.imread. How to send it to cv.imread without saving.

Comment: there is no need to use imread at all.. you already have your image in EditedImage, just copy using .copy() if you want a copy..

Comment: It worked. I am looking  for some other suggestion too for what I have put a different question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67598282/how-to-manage-min-match-count-in-image-comparison-using-canny

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just copy the image to a variable. Why do you have to save it locally?

```
img_clone = EditImg.copy()
```