# How to manage MIN_MATCH_COUNT in image comparison using canny?

Tags: python, opencv, histogram, canny-operator, image-comparison

I am using canny for image comparison. I am getting correct results for matching and non matching objects after comparing using canny image edging. At times it is not giving the right result and for that I need to keep changing the MIN_MATCH_COUNT.
Any solution to keep the MIN_MATCH_COUNT and canny should compare each and every edge of the image.

```
MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 20

img1 = canny.copy()
img2 = canny1.copy()


# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv.SIFT_create()
# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks = 50)
flann = cv.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
# store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
        good.append(m)
if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    M, mask = cv.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv.RANSAC,5.0)
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()
    h,w = img1.shape
    pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst = cv.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)
    img2 = cv.polylines(img2,[np.int32(dst)],True,255,3, cv.LINE_AA)
    print ("Both the images are matching")
else:
    print( "Not enough matches are found and hence images are not same - {}/{} and hence both the images are not matching".format(len(good), MIN_MATCH_COUNT) )
    matchesMask = None
draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0), # draw matches in green color 
                   singlePointColor = None,
                   matchesMask = matchesMask, # draw only inliers
                   flags = 2)
img3 = cv.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,**draw_params)
plt.imshow(img3, 'gray'),plt.show()
```

Below is the image where I am getting result as not matching when MIN_MATCH_COUNT is 20 and if I change  it to 9 then it will say images are matching.
[image]

Similarly in below image also actual ridges of keys are not matching but its still giving the images are matching without considering the matching point.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a relative criteria, so instead of using an asbolute value for MIN_MATCH_COUNT you can use the percentage of matching keypoints over the total number of keypoints of your model. In this way you can set a threshold based on your specific test, let's say..30% (IDK, just an example). That's what I do in a similar issue.
Something like:

```
matching = len(good)/len(kp1)*100
```

In this way 0<matching<100 and represent a percentage of similarity, so you can do:

```
min_threshold = 40

if matching > min_threshold:
...
```

Comment: Can you share some example.

Comment: edited, basically you go from an absolute value to a relative value for the threshold. You still have to experiment in order to find a value that works for you.

Comment: OK...Thanks...Below code is working better for me but not able to identify the if condition to print the images are matching or not matching.                               
img1 = cv.imread('Key1.png',cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)          # queryImage
img2 = cv.imread('Key2.png',cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) # trainImage
# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv.SIFT_create()
# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

Comment: # FLANN parameters
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)   # or pass empty dictionary
flann = cv.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

Comment: # Need to draw only good matches, so create a mask
matchesMask = [[0,0] for i in range(len(matches))]
# ratio test as per Lowe's paper
for i,(m,n) in enumerate(matches):
    if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
        matchesMask[i]=[1,0]
draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0),
                   singlePointColor = (255,0,0),
                   matchesMask = matchesMask,
                   flags = cv.DrawMatchesFlags_DEFAULT)
img3 = cv.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches,None,**draw_params)
plt.imshow(img3,),plt.show()

Comment: Please don't post code in comments.. please open a new question if this is solved. Code is totally unreadable in comments.

Comment: Sure Posting new question.

Comment: Hi added new question.                 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67616711/how-to-add-if-else-for-print-in-flann-image-comparison

Comment: matching = len(matches)/len(kp1)*100
min_threshold = 40

for i,(m,n) in enumerate(matches):
    if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
        matchesMask[i]=[1,0]

        
draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0),
                   singlePointColor = (255,0,0),
                   matchesMask = matchesMask,
                   flags = cv.DrawMatchesFlags_DEFAULT)
img3 = cv.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches,None,**draw_params)
plt.imshow(img3,),plt.show()

if matching > min_threshold:
            print ("Images are same")
else:
                print ("Images are different")

Comment: I used Above code. When I check print matching then every time it is showing me value as 100 and thus I am getting 'Images are same' as matching is always greater than min threshold. Any suggestion?